# Best way to implement recursive slicing of an object e.g. for merge-sort

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, parameter-passing, slice

I'd like to implement a slice on an array object where the object takes care of slicing without losing its properties. My initial implementation:

```
class Array(list):
    @property        #example
    def length(self):
        return len(self)

def foo(array_obj)
   # some type of merge-sort algorithm
   length = array_obj.length
   A = foo(array_obj[:(length//2)]) #pass the 1st half of the array_obj to foo()
   B = foo(array_obj[(length//2):]) #pass the 2nd half of the array_obj to foo()

def main():
... #create an array from numbers in a file
array_a = Array([number for number in map(int, [line.strip() for line in fh])])
foo(array_a)
```

The inner foo ends up taking a list rather than a sliced array_obj instance. (python syntax 3.x) So, array_obj.length, reports: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'length'.

I'm thinking for a recursive sort algorithm, a sort-in-place would probably be more efficient and faster. Other instances may enjoy a deep-copy alternative. Insight and suggestions on the best way to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: What about over-writing `__getitem__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is override the `__getitem__` magic method. In this case, do the following:

```
class Array(list):
    @property        #example
    def length(self):
        return len(self)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return Array(super().__getitem__(index))
        return super().__getitem__(index)
```

Comment: In that case `array_obj[0]` will return Array instance instead of object at index 0

Comment: @Joshua, thank you, this worked for me. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without creating a new Array, but with passing a reference so that sorting can be done in place.